# Google Maps Free API for NGO project

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, maps

I'm building a React app and I would like to use Maps. Google Maps and other Maps APIs have a charge and this project will be free for the community (just like an NGO) so no budget at all.

In this app there is a page to create an Event, so you can type many things and where the Event will happen, and that is where I would like to use Maps, to search and show the location.
I thought that if is there any possibility to use a search box connected to an API just to get the Longitude and Latitude based on the search would be great, but I have no idea how to make it and I was expecting that you could help me find a way. (the thing is: get the information for free)

Just as I create this event, I would like to show this information on the Event page, so where the event will happen. And that would be the second part that I would like to use Maps. Do you know if I just show the location in Maps if I would be charged? If so, then I can use redirection to Google Maps using the Latitude and Longitude that I got from the event creation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, google's search api is not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://www.google.com/nonprofits/offerings/google-earth-and-maps/ for non-profit organizations.